# How to do lazy loading or eager loading with dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a serverless project at aws. I am new to dynamodb, and would like to build 2 tables, Post and Likes.

```
PostsDynamoDBTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: postId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: postId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.POSTS_TABLE}
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.USER_ID_INDEX}
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: userId
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: createdAt
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL

LikesDynamoDBTable:
          Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
          Properties:
            AttributeDefinitions:
              - AttributeName: userId
                AttributeType: S
              - AttributeName: postId
                AttributeType: S
              - AttributeName: likeId
                AttributeType: S
              - AttributeName: createdAt
                AttributeType: S
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: likeId
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: postId
                KeyType: RANGE
            BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
            TableName: ${self:provider.environment.LIKES_TABLE}
            GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
              - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.USER_ID_INDEX}
                KeySchema:
                  - AttributeName: userId
                    KeyType: HASH
                  - AttributeName: createdAt
                    KeyType: RANGE
                Projection:
                  ProjectionType: ALL
```

I am wondering how can I query/scan posts so that I get all posts with likes that are related to them as well?

```
   await this.docClient
    . scan({
      TableName: this.postsTable,
    })
    .promise()
```

Answer (score 3):

DynamoDB is a completely different paradigm than SQL databases.  Storing Posts and Likes in their own tables is a common pattern in SQL databases, because you have the SQL `join` operation.  You do not have a `join` operation in DDB, so you aren't going to get very far building your tables in this way.

It's considered a best practice in DynamoDB to use a single table for your application and pre-join your data (remember, no joins). This probably means your Post and Like data will be stored together under the same partition key.

I would recommend taking the time to watch [this talk on data modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE) in DynamoDB.  This talk is among the best introductions to DDB date modeling that I've seen.